# How to debug in VS Code a Firebase Cloud Function that is fired on a document onDelete?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm having a hard time trying to debug a firebase cloud function, for now what I'm doing is to add some console logs, changing code and deploying everytime.

I've found a couple tutorials on how to do this, but they are too old and doesn't really work anymore.
Besides, these tutorials doesn't show how to debug a function that is fired when a document is deleted on Firebase, which is my case.

For example:

```
exports.DeleteDevelopment = functions.firestore
  .document('developments/{Id}')
  .onDelete(async (snap) => triggers.deleteDevelopment(snap));
```

After this code is fired when a document is deleted inside de developments collection, I would like to set some breakpoints inside my function `deleteDevelopment`

Is there any "easy" way to debug my function inside VS Code?

Thanks,
Bruno

[EDIT]
After trying a little further on this issue, here are some things I've done so far...
I've used the 'firebase init' again, changing some settings on my local environment.
So, this is how I did it:
[image]

Then, back into my function folder, npm install, npm run build, everything ok...

I've run 'firebase emulators:start', and everything initialized...
(besides other logs, my function initialized as below)
functions[DeleteDevelopment]: firestore function initialized.
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your apps. │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┐
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │
├───────────┼────────────────┤
│ Functions │ localhost:5001 │
├───────────┼────────────────┤
│ Firestore │ localhost:8080 │
├───────────┼────────────────┤
│ Database  │ localhost:9000 │
├───────────┼────────────────┤
│ Hosting   │ localhost:5000 │
└───────────┴────────────────┘

Now, the problem is, I still can't debug locally my DeleteDevelopment.
I'm on a trial and error quest without even knowing what I'm doing (I know, it's sad)...
Tried the 'firebase emulators:start --only functions', 'firebase serve --only functions', 'functions deploy DeveleDevelopment', and a couple of combination changing the order of the commands.

If anyone could give a hint to solve this, it would be great!

Thanks again,
Bruno.

Answer (score 0):

Try the firebase server --only functions from the functions directory. The functions emulator should load up any functions you have created. To set a breakpoint on a function running live, you need to create a json configuration file for debugging. There are more steps with examples outline here at this https://medium.com/@david_shortman/build-and-debug-firebase-functions-in-vscode-73efb76166cf